# Angular 2 .ts file not transpiling to .js on save in Visual Studio 2015 ASP.NET Core project

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, angular, asp.net-core

If I make a change to app.component.ts and save the file, the change won't appear in app.component.js until I build the project manually.

My goal is to have Angular 2 code changes reflected in the browser after I save. I shouldn't have to do a build every time.

Here is my **tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing `"compileOnSave": true`. The [TypeScript documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig.json.html) says it only works with Visual Studio 2015 and with the Atom TypeScript plugin. It also requires TypeScript 1.8.4 or higher.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: This worked! None of the other tutorials mentioned compileOnSave. I think it might be a bug in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2?

Comment: For me it compiled on save until I added a tsconfig.json file. Then it stopped working until I added compileOnSave.

Comment: For me it still doesn't work. I have posted my project here https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvPiv6aM2fzRepKV9J_F0-387Zc can anybody please help me

Answer (score -1):

on **Task Runner Explorer** 
go to **Custom** and run `tsc:w`